# Writing query results to a text file

Tags: php

I am a new user of php.

I have one table in mysql database. I have a form which the users use to query the mysql database. I am testing my html form page on my linux laptop which has APACHE server.

I am able to make a connection to the mysql database and display results in the browser.

I am not sure how to capture the results from the variable which has query results which has several rows of data and be able to write the results to a text file in /var/www/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed every time you check if the POST variable is set you use something like

```
if(isset($POST["submit"])){
```

Was that a typo in this post or are you forgetting the underscore?

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

Comment: +1 For actually looking at his code

Comment: I appreciate your time in responding to my questions. I changed $POST["submit"] including an underscore. It displays the record in the browser locally. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array.
And always prepare the variabes for usage in a query if you do not want to get hacked instantly.

Comment: Galkin,Thanks for your suggestions. I will try mysql_fetch_assoc. Could you please explain what you mean by preparing the variables? I initialized the variables in the first part of the php code and then used those variables in the query.Is there a different way?Thank you.

Comment: By preparing the variables I mean sanitizing its values - for example [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). You can also check out [this post on PHP and security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices) - it has a lot of useful links in it.